# Highcharts - tickInterval not working for bar/column charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart with multiple series and a `datetime` x-axis.  I have the chart configured to show labels for each year using `tickInterval`.  This works with line charts but does not work for bar/column charts.

jsFiddle showing how this works with line charts: [line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/g6TwB/)

jsFiddle showing how this does NOT work with column charts: [column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/m7S6B/)

As you can see in the second fiddle, when chart type is 'column' only a few ticks (2005, 2010, and 2015) are displayed instead of 2003-2013 as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't get proper `tickInterval` because there are holes in data especially in series 'Cat7' and 'Cat8'. If you use the same number of points for each series than you will get `tickInterval` for each year. For example:

```
    data: [
        [1041400800000, 0],
        [1072936800000, 0],
        [1104559200000, 0],
        [1136095200000, 0],
        [1167631200000, 0],
        [1199167200000, 1],
        [1230789600000, 0],
        [1262325600000, 0],
        [1293861600000, 0],
        [1325397600000, 1],
        [1357020000000, 0]
    ],
    name: "Cat1"
}, {
```

See updated [example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7S6B/1) and the [same example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7S6B/2/) with `null` instead of zero values.

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like you don't need to fill in every hole in the data - just the endpoints: http://jsfiddle.net/8WnJQ/.

Comment: That was something I also thought about. Most probably you have to "say" on at least one place how much data you have at one x-point.

Comment: Going to wait a bit before accepting this though. Seems like a bit of a hack. I don't really want to be doing this kind of preprocessing, and given that the line charts do behave properly I would assume this is a bug.

Comment: That is possibility. For sure with column chart processing is different. With line chart for one x-tick thera are points which are spread vertically. With column chart for one x-tich there are points which are spread horizontally and calculation is different.

Comment: Turns out filling just the endpoints in doesn't always work.  So Anto's original solution looks to be the best way to resolve this issue.  Hopefully they fix this soon because filling in every point in each series (like a category axis) seems to defeat the purpose a bit of the timeaxis, but oh well.